# Porting to .NETFramework 4.6.1 from .NetCore 2.0

Tags: c#

I'am working on a Asp.NetCore WebApplication Project where i have some dependecies to use that supported on .NetFramework and not on .NetCore ,
I am trying to create another project with asp.net webApplication and to migrate the services that have been used on the .NetCore .
first there is no startup class in the asp.NetWebApplciation , I Created my own class named startup and and not sure about it ,
I added packages for owin.OAuth and owin.host.systemweb and in addition i recreated my data project entities and configuration where I am using entityframeworkCore and not pretty sure if i can use this package when working with .NetFramework
- help needed with the assure of startup that can be created by us ?
- previously i configured connection string in appsetting.json where in asp.net webapplication has no appsetting.json
-am I able to work with entityframeworkcore for my data projects ? if not what to be substitute ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing two things (they *are* confusing, it got me, too):

ASP.NET Core has nothing to do with your Target Framework. You can build an ASP.NET Core project with either .NET Core **or** .NET Framework as a target framework.

So if you need libraries that target the full framework, all you need to do is target the full framework as well. You can **still** have an ASP.NET Core application.

Comment: First , Thanks mate ,
if it is like that then i could change my exist asp.net core project target from .netcore 2.0 to .netframework 4.6 from the prop of the project or somewhere else am not sure but when i try to do that I am not getting other options in the target Framework dropdown list other than netCore where i want to choose the .netframework 4.6 ??
AnyHelpful Idea from this side  ?
what if I want to use this package : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders  , in my data project but this package is only compatable with .NETCore ! any similar for .NetFramework 4.6 ?? 
Thanks